# How to use comparer function inside class with algorithm header?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

This is what my compare function looks like:

```cpp
bool smallest_weight(const size_t& i, const size_t& j) {
    return this->abs_weight[i] < this->abs_weight[j];
}
```

I use this function inside the constructor of the class to initialize some other arrays. This is the code that uses it:

```cpp
size_t best_node = *min_element(
    this->pointer_list[i + 1].begin(),
    this->pointer_list[i + 1].end(),
    smallest_weight
);
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘bool TimeCalculator::smallest_weight(const size_t&, const size_t&)’
```

I can't make the function `static` since it won't be able to access the data inside the class, I'd also like to avoid making the arrays global if possible.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: BTW, you can decrease your amount of keyboarding by stop using the `this->` syntax.  You only need it to differentiate member names from parameter names.  You could change your coding style so members have different names, such as prefixing the members with `m_`.  Less typing means less chance of typos and other defects.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I like to write `this->` since it says that it's a variable of the class and not a variable that I declare somewhere in the class. It's just my personal preference

Comment: I like to write `m_value = parameter1;` since it says that `m_value` is a variable of the class and not a local or parameter value.  It's a lot easier to read, and I'm constantly reading reading other people's code try to figure out how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
size_t best_node = *min_element(
    this->pointer_list[i + 1].begin(),
    this->pointer_list[i + 1].end(),
    [&](const auto& i, const auto& j) noexcept { return this->smallest_weight(i, j); }
);
```

Comment: That would work, but I personally consider `[&]` an antipattern (reasons on request).  There is, in any case, no need to capture `this` by reference.  Using `[this]` as the capture clause would be a better bet.